# Cambiar el tema de tu página web al darle click a un texto o botón

Tags: javascript, html

El día de hoy estaba haciendo pruebas en una página web cuando se me ocurrio hacer un botón (en este caso texto) con el que cambiar el tema de la página.
Principalmente ví que se podía hacer con el siguiente JavaScript (es el que tengo en mi página web):

```
var ctema = document.getElementById("tema").innerHTML;
console.log(ctema);
function tema() {
    if (ctema == "Cambiar al modo claro") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "darkgrey";
    }
}
```

Y el HTML del botón:

```
<header>
  <p id="tema" onclick="tema();">Cambiar al modo claro</p>
</header>
```

Sin embargo no funciona, dandome el error en consola: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML').**
He probado varías cosas, pero no consigo dar con la solución. ¿Alguien que me ayude?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: [Se desaconseja usar manejadores de eventos _inline_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Repliqué tu código usando el **brave browser** y no arrojó ningún tipo
> de error.

Comprende que algunos navegadores web y algunos servicios de alojamiento de aplicaciones web no admiten **onclick inline** declarado directamente en el HTML e inicializando funciones.
Con el tiempo, este recurso está cayendo en desuso y en la actualidad, la mayoría de los navegadores admiten [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Debes tener en cuenta que depende del navegador y si acepta el uso de [*onclick inline*](https://caniuse.com/?search=onclick), tiene soporte.

El abandono de "onclick inline" está relacionado con la seguridad. Te recomiendo que uses [*addEventListener*](https://caniuse.com/?search=addEventListener).

```js
var ctema = document.getElementById("tema") 
ctema.style.cursor = "pointer"
 var dark = false
 
ctema.addEventListener("click", ()=>{

if (dark) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    ctema.textContent = "Cambiar al modo claro";
    dark=false

} else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "darkgrey";
    ctema.textContent = "Cambiar al modo oscuro";
    ctema.style.color ="black"
    dark= true
}


});
```

```html
 <header>

      <p id="tema"> Cambiar al modo claro </p>

 </header>
```

**-** *Como puedes notar, la variable* **dark** *se inicializa como* **false**. *Al hacer clic, el* **background color** *cambia a*
**darkgrey** *y la convierte en* **true**. *Y una vez más, al hacer clic, vuelve al color claro.*

El método addEventListener() recibe dos argumentos.

**1** = es la acción, puede ser un `click`, una interacción con lo que se ingresa en el teclado.
separados por coma `,`
**2** = una función que realiza una acción.

**addEventListener** *(* **"click"** `,` **tema**  *)*

De esta manera, se especifica que cuando ocurra un click, se realizará un evento.

Puede usar una función anónima:

```
ctema.addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "darkgrey";
});
```

o una arrow function:

```
ctema.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "darkgrey";
});
```

Comment: Gracias por la info. Lo probaré en cuanto pueda y te digo si me funciona.

Comment: Bien!! Ya funciona todo gracias. Ahora otro problema que tengo que resolver es que no me deja modificar texto con innerHTML.

Comment: @Prozoon700 añadí una nueva respuesta.